# js how to change id inside cloned form with its own new id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a section called `duplicator1`. I want to clone that section and it works but my issue is when section is cloned `id` of elements are same, so how can I change `id` when section is cloned.

My js functions

```
var countCopies1;
var clone ;

function duplicate() {
    var original = document.getElementById('duplicater1');
    clone = original.cloneNode(true); 
    var countCopies = $('body').html().split('duplicater').length;
    clone.id = "duplicater"+countCopies;
    original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
    countCopies1 = countCopies;
}
```

My table with id duplicater1. When I duplicate it `id` changes to `duplicater2`, `duplicater3` and so on, but my `id` customer, project, post, hours stay the same in new duplicated table. How can I change them & I need in `duplicater2` id `customer1`, `project1`, `post1`, `hours1`.

I will be thankful if u help me!

```
<div id="duplicater1"> 

    <br></br>

  <table class="table table-bordered">

    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th style="width:16%;text-align:center">{Customer}</th>
        <th style="width:16%;text-align:center">{Project}</th>
        <th style="width:16%;text-align:center">{Activity}</th>
        <th style="width:16%;text-align:center">{Hours}</th>
        <th style="width:16%;text-align:center">{Comment}</th>
        <th style="width:5%"> </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

<tbody>

    <td>
        <div class="form-inline" style="text-align:center"><select style="width:200px" id="customer" class="form-control" onchange="getCustomerAddWork(this)">{CUSTOMERS}</select></div>
    </td>

    <td>
        <div class="form-inline" style="text-align:center"><select style="width:200px" id="project" class="form-control" onchange="getProjectAddWork(this)"></select></div>
    </td>

    <td>
        <div class="form-inline" style="text-align:center"><select style="width:200px" id="post" class="form-control"></select></div>
    </td>

     <td>
        <div class="form-inline" style="text-align:center">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="hours" placeholder="{Hours}">
        </div>
        </div>
    </td>

    <td>
        <div class="form-inline" style="margin-bottom:1em;text-align:center">
        <div class="form-group">
            <textarea class="form-control"  id="comment" placeholder="{Comment}"></textarea>
        </div>
        </div>
    </td>

    <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" style="width:70px" 
 onclick="Remove()">{Delete}</button>
        </td>

    </tbody>

 </table>  

 </div>
</div>
    <div class="container-fluid bg-2 text-center" style="margin-top:5em;margin-bottom:3em;">

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="duplicate()">{Add}</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" onclick="AddWork()">{Submit}</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="Redirect()">{Cancel}</button>  

</div>
 </form>
```

Comment: You might benefit from the selector `[id]` - this will return all elements that have an ID attribute. You'll want to change these. That said, why do you even have IDs here? A `name` attribute would be far more appropriate.

Comment: my approach is `data tags` - you do something like `<div class="test" data-id="1">` and to generate next id do `$(this).data('id') + 1`

Comment: If you are replicating elements, using `id` attributes is challenging as id selectors only return the first element they find. While duplicate identifiers are not good practice they are less of a problem functionally when inside a container with a unique identifier, such as `duplicator2/3/4` To add to the already suggested solutions above, and seeing you tagged jQuery you can adjust your selectors to be context aware i.e: `$('#customer', '#duplicator2')` or `$('#customer', '#duplicator3')` though in general I would favor `data-id` attributes as well.

Comment: Check my answer now, I didn't read you wanted to change IDs for inner elements...now it should do the trick

Comment: on performance metrics this syntax `$('body').html().split('duplicater').length;` is tooo much just to get a count of the total elements.. You can simple add a class attribute and then do a `$('.className').length` ... however since the intention is to create uniqueness simply add a datetime Stamp.

Comment: Thanks for help!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have jQuery, I would do something like this:

```
var original = $("#duplicater1");


function duplicate() {
    var countCopies = $("[id^='duplicater']").length + 1;
    var cloned = original.clone();
    var cloned.attr("id", "duplicater" + countCopies);
    $(cloned).find("[id]").each(function(){
        var current = $(this);
        var currentId = current.attr("id");
        var ids = $("[id='" + currentId + "']");
        if(ids.length > 1 && ids[0]==this){
            var newId = currentId.substring(0, currentId - 1);
            current.attr("id", newId + countCopies);
        }

    });
    original.parent().append(cloned);

}
```

Comment: Tony Samperi, Sorry, I'm new here and it was accidentally
Thank u very much for your help!!!

Comment: Don't worry! Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

> My table with id duplicater1. When I duplicate it id changes to
>   duplicater2, duplicater3 and so on, but my id customer, project, post,
>   hours stay the same in new duplicated table. How can I change them & I
>   need in duplicater2 id customer1, project1, post1, hours1.

Yes, as duplicate identifiers are not good markup you should indeed change them.
However, duplicate identifiers within unique identifiable containers are functionally not an issue (Though still should be changed).

To address your actual question, yes you can write a loop that goes through each element within the `duplicator` container and append a number to it and I'm sure there are answers showing you how to and they are perfectly fine.

I would however try to address the duplicate identifier issue in another way that doesn't require maintaining code to do this.

An approach I have been using in numerous web projects in those type of scenarios is to use `data-id` as an attribute to identify the containers and to allow you to group them as well as the elements inside.

*Note, you can use classes or data-xxx or what ever takes your fancy, I personally just prefer data-id for these cases*

Instead of using `<div id="duplicater1/2/3">` just use `<div data-id="duplicater">` to identify the "type" of component/form you are working with.

Inside, do the same with each element, such as `<select data-id="customer">` or `<select data-id="project">`

> This solves the cloning problem all together as you can now clone each
>   duplicator without the need to rename anything at all and you don't
>   need to maintain custom code renaming element identifiers

In regards to the bound events, you don't have to worry about them either as each element when it raises an event such as `getProjectAddWork(this)` is already within context.

Say you trigger the `getProjectAddWork(this)` event and need to get to your duplicator container your are in, you can simple do something similar to `$(this).closest('[data-id="duplicator"]');` or to get to the outer form `$(this).closest('form');` etc..

Sure, you can achieve the same by only renaming the duplicator id as you already do and then do `$(this).closest('#duplicator');` but in my humble opinion I rather prevent duplicate identifiers and not having to maintain code to rename identifiers as well as base selectors on contextual awareness within their respective "component"

*I use jQuery as you tagged your question with it but you can do the same with just plain JavaScript*